# Open source VS propietary ARM debuggers for Linux OS

Tags: linux, debugging, ide, arm

I am on Linux OS and I got acquainted with **arm-none-eabi** tool-chain and **make** building process in order to compile my binaries for ARM based micro-controllers. But things got complicated because I have to deal with assembly language now and it is a harsh World without a decent debugger.

So I bought myself a SEGGER J-LINK EDU probe to debug my applications using JTAG pins on my micro-controllers. But as it turns out Linux has no deecent debugger that would show me register values. I tried working with **openocd** but gave up on that and then I found Seeger's application **JLinkExe** which enables me to read registers, halt my program etc...

But this is all in command line interface and I want to include it in my IDE (I am currently using IDE Kdevelop but am allso familiar with Eclipse IDE)... Well In other words... I am sick of command line and I want fancy debugging tools in my IDE. Are there any free solutions out there that could deliver debugging graphical interface like IAR's:

[image]

or like the one that DS5 from ARM delivers:

[image]

It is getting too hard to do all in command line so if there are any Linux free solutions to include graphical debugging data into IDE I would be very happy. **Otherwise I will have to buy a well documented commercial product...**

Your opinions are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I am currently using a solution with Kdevelop (version 4.7.3) and JLinkGDBServer to debug a microcontroller.

The solution I have found is to import the project, configure a launch (`Run -> Configure Launches`), add a new launch for the program as `New Compiled Binary Launch`.

In the `New Compiled Binary Launch` tab select the path to the executable.
In the `Debug` tab select the path to the `Debugger executable` and create and add a gdb script that suits your needs (in mine I attach to the GDB server, load the program and reset the server).

I still have to launch the JLinkGDBServer manually in the command line, but debugging the application got a lot easier.

Here is the gdb script, which is specific for SWO debugging:

```
target remote localhost:2331
monitor speed 1000

file program.out
load program.out
monitor SWO EnableTarget 209715200 1000000 1 0
thbreak main
monitor reset
```

Ensure the speed value is the correct one.

Comment: Could you add your GDB script? =)